# Mapping domain subdirectory to EC2 instance

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, domain, amazon-web-services

My root domain is currently hosted at Dreamhost (i.e., http://website.com) -- What I am trying to do is point a subdirectory to my EC2 instance -- https://website.com/app would hit my elastic IP, ideally. Is there a preferred way to do this? Would I be better of moving everything to AWS? Any insight would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any way you can use http://app.website.com/ instead? That would just be a simple extra A record rather than having to setup redirects.